# Angular subscribe and read/write same variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 7.

I have a global vector in the x.component.ts file and I have several subscriptions in order to get some values from server.

Every time that the brwoser receives a value the value is inserted in the vector and several functions (and services) compute operations about the vector (sometimes the vector is passed function like parameter).

I have a doubt: I need to put some locks or no?

I don't wish that the vector is reading and writing by two functions "in the same time".

I mean: I know that javaScript is single thread but I don't wish that thread stop in order to execute anothers operations because anothers data are ready also if the the old thread don't access anymore this variable.

Comment: Wrap operations inside Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, there would be two scenarios in your code:

1- The service, which is responsible to read/write, should be instantiated once for each vector. So by restricting your service like below could do it

```
@Injectable()
export class VectorUpdateService {
  vector: Vector;
  constructor(private vectorService: VectorService) {}
  
  // read vector
  fetchCachedVector(id: number) {
    if (!this.vector) {
      this.vector = this.vectorService.getVectorById(id);
    }
    return this.vector;
  }
}
```

For more info, [Multiple service instances (sandboxing)](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#multiple-service-instances-sandboxing) could be handy.

You can do it by [Singleton design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) as well.

2- Handling same operations that you stated. As I know, this case is really similar to asynchronous programming in JavaScript. It's handled by defining job and job queue. You don't need to worry about it.

I hope I could help you.